# Install VLC on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-mint, vlc-media-player

I would like to install VLC player on Linux Mint in order to watch a movie.

I used to use Fedora, and to install VLC I would use `yum -install VLC`

What is the equivalent command in Linux Mint?

Comment: Thank you mister K. Is there actually somewhere i could read the rules for good posts ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend installing VLC Media Player by using official packages from [VideoLAN : Downloads](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/#download) by choosing your GNU/Linux distribution.

See the Downloads Section on the Site:

[image: See the Downloads Section on the Site]

Either way you can just open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and write the following commands to install vlc media player.

Step 1 : Add VLC PPA to your System to get latest VLC version

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

Step 2 : Update Repository

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Step 3 : Install VLC package

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
```

If you are using older versions of Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint, you can use above PPA to install/upgrade to latest VLC version.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, here is what actually goes. In order to watch the movie I tried simply sudo apt-get install vlc, before having your answer.        My prompt gave this message :  VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[09933df8] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[098951b0] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[098951b0] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0991bda8] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax

Comment: I have the log from the installation, i saved it in a text file.  It's Linux Mint >17, 18 i think.          The command was actually      sudo apt-get install vlc-nox